# Content encoding error when using linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I'm developer working on integration between our product and LinkedIn. It's been decided we use https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization to authenticate user. I found out the following issue, that I'll explain in detail below.

**Positive scenario, everything works as expected:**

when using valid client_id, everything is fine. To make everything clear, please see this URL (API key replaced with fake one):

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=VALID_API_KEY&state=b4ac5e2ab5404d6fad2f25521d83e825&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2Fapply-app%2Fpages%2Fsocial-networks%2Flinkedin%2Fauthenticated%3FsiteIdentifier%3DPIUFK026203F3VBLZ6G79V7OU%26token%3Db4ac5e2ab5404d6fad2f25521d83e825

**When I remove client_id, everything is also fine** and message is displayed (Missing client_id. A valid client_id is required to proceed.)

But **when I use invalid client_id in browser I receive Content Encoding Error and http status code 500**. URL: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=invalid_client_id&state=b4ac5e2ab5404d6fad2f25521d83e825&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2Fapply-app%2Fpages%2Fsocial-networks%2Flinkedin%2Fauthenticated%3FsiteIdentifier%3DPIUFK026203F3VBLZ6G79V7OU%26token%3Db4ac5e2ab5404d6fad2f25521d83e825

And the most interesting part goes here: **when I fetch same URL using either `wget` or even java `HttpConnection.connect()` there result is different: HTTP status code 200 and html response**. But when I started to analyze given output, I noticed that is ends up unexpectedly after `<ul class="permissions`, so it must me error in your code, that requires fixing.

I reported that, because it's quite inconvenient to support such behavior. Could you please inform me if you have any plans to fix this? If you need any further details regarding steps to reproduce this issue, please do not hesitate to contact me.

Best regards,

Piotr

Comment: the difference is explained by the headers set; to mimic the browser behaviour you could use `curl -v -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" `

Comment: Hi Hans, I understand this, but anyway it does not have influence on fact that there is evident bug.